# Correct word for a triangle with truncated points?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, shapes

Is there a correct or technical term for **a two-dimensional hexagon in which three sides are significantly longer than the others**, resembling a triangle with the points cut off? Specifically, a shape similar to each of the letters in this logo:

[image]

So I'm looking to fill in something like "The logo shows the letters E and A in the form of a _______, one over the other".

Comment: Unsurprisingly, they are called *truncated* triangles. The term can be applied to any polygon (or polyhedron).

Comment: If you're looking for a term-of-art in graphic design, you might want to ask on the [SE Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: As far as I can tell, the "E" is an irregular, convex hexagon, and the "A" is an irregular, non-convex nonagon.

Comment: @JohnFeltz Less a term of art, more a reasonably accurate term that I can use in descriptions (of the solar collectors in a Dyson sphere, to be precise) without needing to explain it in detail.

Comment: I agree with Richard Kayser. I'm sure that most of us tend to think of shapes like pentagons, hexagons, etc, they way we think of squares...that is, that their sides are of equal length...but that's not mandated any more than that triangles must have equal length sides in order to be a triangle. What is equal, of course, is the number of sides & angles. But that's as far as it goes, unless defined as equilateral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mick wrote in a comment, they are called ***truncated triangles***.

Truncation (geometry) — [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Truncation_(geometry))

> In geometry, a truncation is an operation in any dimension that cuts polytope vertices, creating a new facet in place of each vertex.
>
> In general any polyhedron (or polytope) can also be truncated with a degree of freedom as to how deep the cut is.
>
> [image: Parametric truncations of a triangle]